# Can I purchase ticket on the spot at Train station Geneva Cornavin instead of online?

Tags: trains, airports, switzerland

I will be landing at Geneva airport (Switzerland) in the coming mid June.
As I would like to go to Metabief, France, I am thinking to take train from Train station Geneva Cornavin (near Geneva airport) to Vallorbe followed by a bus to Metabief.

[This website](https://www.sbb.ch/) sells train tickets.
However, I am not sure whether my flight would be delayed and so I am not planning to purchase online.

As this is my first time travelling to Geneva airport, I am not sure whether I can purchase train ticket on the spot.

Comment: Genève-Cornavin is the main train station in Geneve; it would be absolutely inconceivable that it doesn't have operational ticket vending machines issuing regional train tickets. But if you're arriving by air, why are you not starting from Genève-Aéroport station instead of Cornavin?

Answer (score 2):

One-way tickets in Switzerland are valid for the whole day (unless you buy a specific Supersaver Ticket), so you can easily buy it online a few days before you arrive and take the printout with you. What you need to know though is whether you are going to take the connection where you change trains in Lausanne, or the one where you change trains in Renens. Tickets for one can not be used for the other.

And to answer your actual question: Yes, you can buy tickets on all train stations. On the smaller ones there will be only ticket machines though, but if you have a credit card you should be fine.

PS: Actually, depending on when you arrive, it's probably either

[image]

or the same connection starting at 11:32.

Comment: It may be the official rules that you can't use a via-Lausanne ticket to change at Renens -- but it looks hard to enforce. As far as I can see, the train you would change _to_ at Renens will have left Lausanne just a few minutes earlier. It would be hard for the conductor to know you haven't been on board the whole time.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The ticket via Renens is 10% cheaper. As a tourist you probably can talk yourself out of any problems in such a situation :-)

Comment: @nohillside They *will* give you a fine, but it serves as a valid ticket to your destination, plus any non-citizen/resident can wipe their bottom with it, especially if giving a fake address